# Microsoft Speech Synthesis, SpeakSsmlAsync with out lang attribute

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, ssml, microsoft-speech-api, microsoft-speech-platform

I am using Microsoft Speech Synthesis to play my SSML string using  `public Prompt SpeakSsmlAsync(string ssmlText);` and i got a requirement where i should not use `xml:lang`but when i remove xml:lang attribute from the `ssml` string i am getting below exception

> 'speak' requires attribute 'xml:lang'

So is there a way that i can play my SSML string without using `xml:lang` attribute and let speech engine handle it ?

**What i want to play but fails :**

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis">
  helloo
</speak>
```

**Working one with lang attribute:**

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xm:lang="en-US">
  helloo
</speak>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get the "requirement that should not use `xml:lang`"? According to the [W3C Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-speech-synthesis-20040907/#S3.1.2):

> `xml:lang` is a **required attribute** specifying the language of the root document.

Comment: @itminus thanks, it is mandatory attribute.